# why is image not respecting postion absolute?

Tags: css

Can someone explain why search icon is not on the top of input bar in the below code despite the fact that its absolutely positioned?

Thanks

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
    <input type="text" style="height: 32px; width: 100%">
    <img style="position: absolute; right: 0; height: 32px" src="https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/523/posts/27345/preview_image/search-icon-large.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: because image is position: absolute, it should  be placed over input bar

Comment: Just add `top:0` to it's style and it'd go up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, but you need to also specify a `top` position:

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
    <input type="text" style="height: 32px; width: 100%">
    <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; height: 32px" src="https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/523/posts/27345/preview_image/search-icon-large.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`position:absolute` may cause some appearance/visibility problems. You can use the `background-image` option to add a search icon to the right of the input.

```css
   input {
  background: url("https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/523/posts/27345/preview_image/search-icon-large.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 32px;
  background-position: right center;
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #4B89DA
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter keywords here..." />
```